# Error in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, select

Iam taking a name from user to search in my database from page search.php.

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("amdsvcjdsvhck");
$re=$_GET['text'];

$sql="select sdf from contact where zip = '$re'";
$ess=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($ess);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
{$fow=mysql_fetch_assoc($ess);
echo '<div>'.$fow['zip'].'</div>' ; 
}
?>
```

Now this page is giving error when i pass single quote(') or backslash(`\`) in name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$re=$_GET['text'];
$re = mysql_real_escape_string($re);
$sql="select sdf from contact where zip = '".$re."'";
```

Comment: The reason you got this error is that the character ' ends a string in a MySQL query. So in a query like `select name, address from contact where name = 'John O'Connor'`, MySQL thinks it needs to look for someone called `John O`. It doesn't look beyond that single quote. And then it gets mightily confused when it sees `Connor'` in that query - the string had already ended, right? That's why you need to escape any single quotes that are not intended to be string demarcators, using the mysql_real_escape_string function.